# why click on div do not automatically click on tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, razor

I am using MVC-5 and in my view i have a number of divs arranged horizontally and just below each divs i have tabs. 
Each div is arranged such that it contains tabs just below it.

Now what  i have to do  ?
I have to click on div and upon clicking the div must automatically click the tab just below it.(i don't want manual )

My try to do it :

I have created a Onclick event of div and i have assigned ID to that tab.
  But the problem is that tab  is never clicked on clicing to the respectivce **div**.

My code to do so is:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="col-md-2" id="Active" onclick="activeCircleClick('tab1')">
        <div id="active" style="height: 125px;">
            //here is something
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="width:1300px;">
    <div style="width:100%;">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-pills nav-justified" role="tablist" id="myTab">
            <li class="active" id="activeList">
                <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Active device list</a>
                <span class="col-md-12" id="activeDeviceStatus" style="text-align: center;"></span>
            </li>           
        </ul>
    </div>

<script>
    function activeCircleClick(el)
    {
        alert("test1:" +el);
        selectTab(el);  
    }
    function selectTab(tabId)
    {
        alert('test2:' + tabId);
        var tab = $("#" + tabId);
        if (typeof tab != 'undefined')
        {
            e.preventDefault()
            tab.tab('show');
        }
    }

</script>
```

My both the alert message popups but it don't click the tab below this div which i have clicked.

How to make it happen ?

Comment: `href="#tab1"` is this where you're basing this line `var tab = $("#" + tabId);`?

Comment: @DigitalDouble yes..

Comment: try adding `id="tab1"` to this `<a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">`

Comment: And by the way, can you share your `tab()` function as well

Comment: @DigitalDouble thanks but...plz explain tab1 is id of what ? please explain

Comment: Of this guy `<a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Active device list</a>`. Because you're selecting `#tab1` with jQuery but you don't have an element with that ID.

Comment: I added id="tab1" and it till do not work.

Comment: I just have 6 points not enough to chat

Comment: There are at least 5 issues with the code/HTML shown and possibly duplicate IDs too. I have outlined most issues below, but can you please show the full output HTML of the page (as saved from your browser, not source). That will allow correction of any remaining issues.

Answer (score -1):

I just soved my issue by doing this:

```
 function activeCircleClick(el)
    {
        $('#tab1').bind('click', function () { });
        $('#tab1').trigger('click');
    }
```